# How do I insert strings into an array of an array?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to insert strings into an array of an array but it's not working. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
[string[]] $workArray::new(6,2)

$workArray[0,1] = "C:\Users\"
$workArray[0,2] = "Document.xlsm"
```

However I'm getting this error:
**"Unable to index into an object of type System.String."**

Any suggestions I'll be forever grateful!

Comment: Call the array constructor like this: `$workArray = [string[,]]::new(6, 2)`

Comment: @zett42 thanks. I called the constructor like that and then tried to add the strings, getting another error now : Index was outside the bounds of the array. Do arrays start a 1 in powershell?

Comment: @CluelessDawg1337 Arrays start at 0 in PowerShell, so `$workArray[0, 0]` and `$workArray[0, 1]` for the code in the example. If you get into the habit of putting a space after a comma, it makes it easier to read.

Comment: My first comment apparently requires PS 7.x. In PS 5.x you need this syntax instead: `$workArray =New-Object 'string[,]' 6, 2`

Answer (score 0):

```
$workArray = [string[,]]::new(6, 2)
$workArray[0,0] = "C:\Users\"
$workArray[0,1] = "Document.xlsm"
```

PowerShell is zero indexed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2